# Угол между отрезком и Ox

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, геометрия

Как по двум точкам `A = (x0,y0)`, `B = (x1,y1)` узнать, какой угол составляет отрезок `AB` с осью `Ox`?

Comment: Это же простая школьная геометрия, а не крутой `алгоритм`... Находим разницу по x, y, делим, считаем арктангенс.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например

```
atan2(y1 - y0, x1 - x0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть красивая формула скалярного произведения векторов: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так что, поскольку вектор `AB = (x1-x0,y1-y0)`, то, понятно, что косинус угла равен `(x1-x0)/sqrt((x1-x0)*(x1-x0)+(y1-y0)*(y1-y0))`. Поскольку точки у вас не совпадающие, деления на 0 стопроцентно не будет.

P.S. Но решение @VladD более корректное. Я забыл про `atan2`, помнил только `atan`...

Comment: Почему более корректное?

Comment: @viktor Потому что одной функцией, обходит все деления на нуль, и к тому же точно учитывает квадрант.

Comment: Зато решение со скалярным произведением обобщается на трёхмерный случай, в отличие от `atan2`.

Comment: @VladD Это так, но тут настолько конкретная задача, еще и к оси `Ox` привязанная, что для нее лучше `atan2`...

Answer (score 1):

Формулировка вопроса неоднозначна.
Геометрический угол между лучами АВ и OX следует считать по формуле

`atan2(abs(y1-y0),x1-x0)`